# Recyclerview Grid layout item cut issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout, gridlayoutmanager

I want to display list in recyclerView with grid layout with 2 columns. But when i apply item decor class then item is cutting from right side. Please checl below screenshot and code for the same. Do let me know if anyone have any idea on this.

[image]

**Row file xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.sg.gbb.ui.tourplantcollection.viewmodel.PlantCollectionAdapterViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="164dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/screen_bg"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="164dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/gbb_app_name"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@color/flower_bg" />

                <com.sg.gbb.ui.custom.GBBTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvOrderOn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@{viewModel.code}"
                    android:textColor="@color/greyishBrown"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    app:customFont="@string/gardens_light" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

**My recyclerView file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.sg.gbb.ui.tourplantcollection.viewmodel.PlantCollectionViewModel" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:background="@color/black_80_opacity"
            android:contentDescription="@string/gbb_app_name" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_edit_profile"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.sg.gbb.ui.custom.GBBTextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleTextview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/plant_collection_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/greyishBrown"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    app:customFont="@string/gardens_bold" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/plantCollectionRV"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    app:adapter="@{viewModel.plantList}"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
                    app:spanCount="2"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/item_plant_collection" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/divider" />

            <com.sg.gbb.ui.custom.GBBButton
                android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_dismiss_button"
                android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onBackClicked()}"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:text="@string/back"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/done_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                app:buttonFont="@string/gardens_bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

Item decor file :

```
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

/**
 * Created by Android Studio
 * User: Ailurus(ailurus@foxmail.com)
 * Date: 2015-10-28
 * Time: 15:20
 */
public class EqualSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int spanCount;
    private int spacing;
    private boolean includeEdge;
    private int headerNum;

    public EqualSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge, int headerNum) {
        this.spanCount = spanCount;
        this.spacing = spacing;
        this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
        this.headerNum = headerNum;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) - headerNum; // item position

        if (position >= 0) {
            int column = position % spanCount; // item column

            if (includeEdge) {
                outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

                if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                    outRect.top = spacing;
                }
                outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
            } else {
                outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
                if (position >= spanCount) {
                    outRect.top = spacing; // item top
                }
            }
        } else {
            outRect.left = 0;
            outRect.right = 0;
            outRect.top = 0;
            outRect.bottom = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing fix `layout_width` from `CardView` and make it `match_parent`.

Comment: @ADM Thank you so much! It worked. You can post as an answer i can accept it for future visitors

Answer (score 3):

You **fixed** the `layout_width` of `Card View`

as `android:layout_width="164dp"`

this is the issue,

you should have set it to `match_parent` to get a flexible and *uncut* layout irrespective of the size of the display.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your `row.xml`

try not to fix cardView width

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.sg.gbb.ui.tourplantcollection.viewmodel.PlantCollectionAdapterViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/screen_bg"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="164dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/gbb_app_name"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@color/flower_bg" />

                <com.sg.gbb.ui.custom.GBBTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvOrderOn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@{viewModel.code}"
                    android:textColor="@color/greyishBrown"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    app:customFont="@string/gardens_light" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```